# GA using 2 dimensions in Dashboard widget

Tags: google-analytics, widget, dashboard

We have setup a custom dimension for Author name (Author) and i want to create a dashboard widget showing the Author and Page Title, both dimensions.

The problem is that GA dashboard widgets are limited and i want to know if i can use 2 dimensions in a widget.

Comment: Not  that I know of (except in realtime widgets which does not help you). However if you have a custom dimension to spare you can use an advanced filter and copy author name and page title into a single custom dimension and display that in the dashboard (will not work with historical data and might be a waste of custom dimensions, though).

Comment: Thanks @EikePierstorff, yep that would be a waste of a CD. Trying to build some Dashboards for different authors but being only able to display 1 dimension in a Dashboard widget is limiting.

Answer (score 0):

GA Dashboard widgets can only display 1 dimension.

Comment: I would create a list of authors then, with a click-through link leading to custom report displaying as many custom dimensions you need.